# NestJS - How to access post body using @Body() decorator?

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

```
import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MyService } from 'my.service';
import { MyDto } from './dto/my.dto';

@Controller('my-route')
export class MyController {

    constructor(private readonly _myService: MyService) {}

    @Post()
    async  myMethod(@Body() myDto: MyDto) {
        console.log(myDto); // undefined
        return await this._myService.doStuff(myDto.elementOfInterest); // Passes undefined variable into method.
    }
}
```

I'm confused about the proper way to access the body form data from a POST in Nest. The documentation and examples all show simple use of the `@Body()` decorator preceding the name of a parameter which will contain the body (or a specific element in the body if a parameter is used). Yet in my example above, the body is never populated, and the method is called with `myDto` being undefined. Even changing its type to a string and simply passing a single key/value pair in the body of my POST leaves it undefined.

What's the correct way to handle POST bodies in Nest?

Comment: Did you add any global `Pipe` or `Interceptor`? I just made a quick check from a blank Nest project, creating a `@Post()` controller with a `@Body()` parameter, and I got it working as expected.

**Edit** - I just tried your exact code, without MyDto and MyService, and it worked too. Which version of NestJS are you using?

Comment: No pipes or interceptors. I tested in both 4.5.10 and 4.6.6 and had the same behavior. When I send form data to the server, the code executes, but the body parameter is undefined.

Comment: Also, keep in mind to set `Content-Type` request header into `application/json`.

Comment: That solved it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Kamil Mysliwiec's comment about `Content-Type` was the solution.

> Also, keep in mind to set `Content-Type` request header into `application/json`.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone stumbles on my problem.
I had this issue too, but for me was it in the server setup in the `main.ts`.

I set this code to include a ssl certificate to work with https, but only in production

```
let serverOptions = null;
if (environment.production) {
    const httpsOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(environment.sslKeyPath),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(environment.sslCertPath),
    };

    serverOptions = { httpsOptions };
}
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, serverOptions)
```

but apparently creating a server with options `null`, will break it.

So I changed it to something like this, since it works with undefined

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, serverOptions ?? undefinded)
```

alternatively do something like this, cause I don't know if setting the options to undefined is safe

```
const app = serverOptions ? await NestFactory.create(AppModule, serverOptions) : await NestFactory.create(AppModule)
```

Hope this helps someone with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure it's a Post request instead of get.